# How to localize Libgdx app name for iOS and RoboVM?

Tags: android, ios, libgdx, robovm

My LibGDX project runs on Android and iOS. The Android app name is specified in the manifest:

```
<application
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    ...
```

So, it takes the app name from the android strings.xml file. How can I achieve same behaviour with RoboVM and iOS? I would like to localize the app name later. Therefore it should take the same app name from the Android strings.xml file too.

My robovm.properties file:

```
app.version=1.0
app.id=com.mycom.myapp
app.mainclass=com.mycomp.myapp.IOSLauncher
app.executable=IOSLauncher
app.build=1
app.name=My App Name
```

My robovm.xml file:

```
<config>
<executableName>${app.executable}</executableName>
...
```

Comment: I'm afraid it is not possible to achieve what you need easily. 

RoboVM does not provide such flexibility, you'll have to parse strings.xml from your Android project and update robovm.properties before each build to make sure `app.name` matches `@string/app_name`.

Gradle task or any custom script (also called by Gradle during every build) should do a trick but that's slightly out of scope of your question

Comment: Sry, I missed your comment. Wouldn't that mean that the preferred language is chosen during build? In this case it will not change app name anymore if the user changes its device language.